# How can a ROS Topic has publisher None?

Tags: ros, robotics, gazebo-simu

I'm new to ROS and exploring it by using the Husky robot. So when I checked topics after launching it with Gazebo, some of the topics have publisher None:

```
$rostopic info /husky_velocity_controller/odom
Type: nav_msgs/Odometry

Publishers: None

Subscribers: 
 * /ekf_localization (http://localhost:33585/)
```

So how can a ROS Topic has a None publisher?

Comment: Here it just means that the ekf node has created a subscriber for that topic and no node has created a publisher.

Comment: Topics are listet if a publisher OR subscriber exists. So in this case a subscriber waits for a publisher coming up.